# Did NASA director Jim Bridenstine really make sure that Artemis gets done in a way different than how the US "House of Representatives put forward"?

Tags: nasa, cost, government, artemis-program

**update:** Aviation Week November 8, 2020: [NASA Chief Plans To Step Aside Under Biden](https://aviationweek.com/defense-space/space/nasa-chief-plans-step-aside-under-biden)

---

In the "Angry Astronaut" video *NASA'S Lunar Gateway Announcement - This REALLY matters to Artemis, SpaceX and lunar exploration* the curmudgeon-like yet humorous commentator has plenty to say, including:

> Angry Decree 1: No more than 50 screw ups on a test flight

A bit after `16:10` the narrator says (my own, amateur unofficial transcription):

> But since that time, Jim Bridenstine has proven himself to be an effective administrator, and he has a lot of insight, and a lot of really good ideas.
>
> And I think in many ways he knows that his days may be numbered, and that’s one of the reasons why he put this agreement in place, among many other things, **to make certain that Artemis proceeds the way that he wants it, and not the way that the House of Representatives put forward**, handing everything over to “these guys” (holding a coffee cup that appears to be Boeing-related based on subsequent context)

**Question:** What is the context and back story related to this apparent assertion that NASA director Bridenstine is making sure things get done in a way different than how the US "House of Representatives put forward"?

I don't think its meant to be taken 100% literally, but to what situation does this refer?